# PHP: сравнение строк

Tags: php, строки

Кусочек кода

```
$exe = $_POST['exe'];
//@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
$uid = $_POST['uid'];
$exe="block";
$uid=875;


if (!isset($exe) || !isset($uid) || $exe != "add2fr" || $exe !== "block" || $exe != 'alert' || $exe != 'stopfr' || $exe != 'unblock' || $exe != 'sendpm' || $exe != 'confr') {
er(3);
}
```

Всегда на этом код стопорится. Не нужно лишний раз напоминать мне о том, что сначала нужно isset(), а потом присваивать значение переменной. Я всегда так "неправильно" делаю.

---

Вопрос о том как сравнить строки. Можно ссылок натыкать.

Я и в двойные и в одинарные скобки заключал `block`, и сравнивал `!==`, и скобки ставил,

```
($exe != "block")
```

но не получается правильно сравнить.

Comment: Человек, ты с ума сошел?

Comment: незнаю. уже утро :(

Comment: ты написал ОЧЕНЬ плохой код. так НЕ ДЕЛАЮТ. НИКОГДА. это просто ЧУДОВИЩНО, иди поспи, потом почитай любую книгу по программированию.

Comment: хорошая идея.  ладрно - я тспать - может днем сам посмеюсь над тем что нап исал.

Comment: @root_xPovierennyy Напиши что ты хочешь получить от условия. А то в вопросе одно пишешь в ответе другое.

Comment: пишу словами (и тут вы поймете почему такая ошибка у меня  возникла). Если $exe или $uid НЕ установлены ИЛИ $ехе не равно stopfr ИЛИ $ехе НЕ равно block ИЛИ $ехе НЕ равно.... ну и так далее. Но если, например $ехе будет равно block, то оно НЕ будет равно другим условиям - отсюда и ошибка. Ошибка ИЗНАЧАЛЬНО появилась в самой формулировке условия на этапе обдумывания.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Откройте для себя switch-case.

```
switch($exe) {
     case "add2fr":
     case "block":
     case 'alert':
     case 'stopfr':
     case 'unblock':
     case 'sendpm':
     case 'confr':
         // Тут делаем то, что должны в случае, если $exe равен какому-то из кейсов
         break;
     default:
         // Тут делаем то, что должны в случае, если $exe не равен ни одному из вышеперечисленных условий
}
```

Comment: у меня перед switch проверяется значение по которому будет работать switch. Но зачем такая повторная проверка? Я уже понял что сам switch и проверяет значения.

Comment: if это повторная проверка, которая реализуется с помощью default в switch

Comment: каждый Человек имеет право на тормоза. уже понял.

Answer (score 3):

```
if(in_array($str ,array("add2fr","block",'alert','stopfr','unblock','sendpm','confr')){
do_something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!isset($exe)
 || !isset($uid) // ow. so oops
 || $exe != "add2fr" 
 || $exe !== "block"  //ooops
 || $exe != 'alert' 
 || $exe != 'stopfr' 
 || $exe != 'unblock' 
 || $exe != 'sendpm'
 || $exe != 'confr')
```

Comment: та не пойму я ничего :(

Comment: поспишь и поймешь. представь себе, ты заказал меню с условиями " я не хочу если не или крабы или если не и морковка или если морковка то или лук." ты примерно такой ужас написал.

Comment: ps. строки сравниваются в php оператором `==`  (можно `===`  в новых версиях, для убийственной точности)

Comment: кажись туже дошло. :) спасибо.это я про морковку и лук.

Comment: мне надо быть перегворщиком полицейским.

Answer (score -1):

уже исправил, но на сегодняшнее утро уже достаточно.

```
  if (!isset($exe) || !isset($uid) && $exe != 'add2fr' && $exe != 'block' && $exe != 'alert' && $exe != 'stopfr' && $exe != 'unblock' && $exe != 'sendpm' && $exe != 'confr') {
er(3);
}
```

Скажите, что и это чудовищно не правильно?, но ведь все УЖЕ работает так как нужно.

---

Что я хотел и как получилась ошибка. Условие такое: Если $exe или $uid НЕ установлены ИЛИ $ехе не равно stopfr ИЛИ $ехе НЕ равно block ИЛИ $ехе НЕ равно.... ну и так далее.

НО если, например $ехе будет равно block, то оно НЕ будет равно другим условиям - отсюда и ошибка. Ошибка ИЗНАЧАЛЬНО появилась в самой формулировке условия на этапе обдумывания.

Comment: Не, нуачо. Если наугад тыкать в клавиши, то когда-нибудь и фейсбук напишется.

Comment: чьо там фейсбук. можно и получше придумать. А с ИЛИ\И у меня бывает такое :(